# How do I get the "Name" of a "Release" in Rally?

Tags: rally

The release is an object. How do I get just the name inside this object. 
General a Release looks something like this:

```
"Release": {
    "ObjectID": 12345,
    "Name": "2014 Q3",
    "StartDate": "2014-07-01 18:00:00.0",
    "ReleaseDate": "2014-10-01 16:59:59.0"
}
```

How do I get just the "Name"?

Here is my code:

```
_getStoreForopenDefect: function() {
    return {
        find: {
            _TypeHierarchy: { '$in' : [ 'Defect' ] },
            Children: null,
            _ProjectHierarchy: this.getContext().getProject().ObjectID,
            _ValidFrom: {'$gt': Rally.util.DateTime.toIsoString(Rally.util.DateTime.add(new Date(), 'day', -120)) },
            State: "Open",
            Release: "8.0" <<<<<<<<<< Right  is where I want to pass the release
        },
        fetch: ['Severity','Release','Project'],
        hydrate: ['Severity','Release','Project'],
        sort: {
            _ValidFrom: 1
        },
        context: this.getContext().getDataContext(),
        limit: Infinity
    };
}
```

I want grab Release and pass it to "Release" under my "Find" in the above code, so that my search is narrowed down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using lookback api.  Release will need to be specified by its ObjectID in your find object:

```
Release: 12345
```

Or, if you have multiple projects in scope then you'll need to query for the like releases with the same name and dates and then specify all of them:

```
Release: {'$in': [12345, 23456, 34567]}
```